# :conditions deprecation warning rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deprecation-warning

i am receiving deprecation warning:

DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Contact.belongs_to :customer declaration are deprecated: :conditions. Please use a scope block instead. For example, the following:

```
has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
```

should be rewritten as the following:

```
has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
```

Here is the line with :condition

```
belongs_to :customer, foreign_key: 'contactable_id',\
                      conditions: "contacts.contactable_type = 'Customer'"
```

I just try some variants, but can't fix. Maybe i am missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
belongs_to :customer, -> { where(contactable_type: 'Customer') },
           foreign_key: 'contactable_id'
```

Comment: thanks, this one is working. looks like  i was missing brackets inside curly braces. Thanlks